# Show div expanding out from middle out in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I want to show my `div` when the user generates the trigger. The animation which I want to use showing the `div` is such that the `div` is rendered starting from its centre and then gaining its height by expanding in both directions(up and down) gradually. Here is the snippet of what I have tried. The `div` starts rendering from left. What I want is it starts rendering from middle of its height.

```js
$("#km1").click(function() {
  $(".homePopup").animate({
    width: "730px",
    height: "200px"
  }, 800);
})
```

```css
.homePopup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="km1">Know more</a>
<div class="homePopup"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could animate the `margin` as well to achieve this effect.

Set the initial `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` half of the final `height`; and `margin-left` and `margin-right` half of the final `width`. Then when you increase the `width` and `height`, decrease the `margin` as well.

```js
$("#km1").click(function() {
  $(".homePopup").animate({
    width: "730px",
    height: "200px",
    margin: '0'
  }, 800);
})
```

```css
.homePopup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 100px 365px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="km1">Know more</a>
<div class="homePopup"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to position the element in the middle from the beginning. I'm setting the left absolute position to 50%, then moving the element back -50% of itself so that it is in the middle.

Check out CSS transform:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

```js
$("#km1").click(function() {
  $(".homePopup").animate({
    width: "730px",
    height: "200px"
  }, 800);
})
```

```css
.homePopup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="km1">Know more</a>
<div class="homePopup"></div>
```

******UPDATE******

Here is the css to run the animation from the middle of the window's height:

```
.homePopup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I divided the width and height by four to and added that to the left and top to obtain the center animation requested.

```js
$("#km1").click(function() {
  $(".homePopup").animate({
    width: "730px",
    height: "200px",
    left: "0px",
    top: "0px"
  }, 800);
})
```

```css
.homePopup {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 182px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="km1">Know more</a>
<div class="homePopup"></div>
```